# How to use :after to clear floats

Tags: css

Why isn't this use of **:after** succeeding in clearing the float so that content appears on a new line?

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N3Rm6/)**

**HTML**:

```
<div id="left-block"></div>
<div id="right-block"></div>
<div>Content</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#left-block {float:left; border:1px solid red; width:200px; height:200px;}
#right-block {float:left; border:1px solid green; width:200px; height:200px;}
#right-block:after {clear:both; content:""; display:block;}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your html as follows:

```
<div id="clearfix">
    <div id="left-block"></div>
    <div id="right-block"></div>
</div>
<div>Content</div>
```

And you css as:

```
#left-block {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
#right-block {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid green;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
#clearfix:after {
    clear:both;
    content:"";
    display: table;
}
```

Basically you need to give the floated divs a parent and give the `:after` pseudoclass a display of `table`.
This is because you need to clear the parent of the floated divs and not the children itself

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D7ufV/)

Answer (score 2):

Just give "clear" for your content. [**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/N3Rm6/6/)

**CSS**

```
 .content {
    clear:both;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">Content</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your divs inside a class having a `clear`, Having `clear:both` after the floated divs practice was fine but it introduced elements into the page that we really didn't need if there was a better way. Try involving CSS pseudo-elements on a parent element!

**HTML**

```
<div class="clear">
   <div id="left-block"></div> 
   <div id="right-block"></div>
</div>
<div>Content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#left-block {float:left; border:1px solid red; width:200px; height:200px;}
#right-block {float:left; border:1px solid green; width:200px; height:200px;}
.clear:before,
.clear:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clear:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/N3Rm6/7/)

Answer (score 0):

With same html proposed by Anubhav, I suggest to simply add "overflow:hidden" to the "clearfix" box, without need of generated content! :-)

```
#clearfix
{
   overflow:hidden
}
```